# ¿Cómo puedo reordenar o normalizar los valores de la columna AUTO_INCREMENT en MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Tengo la siguiente tabla en MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `google_analytics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url_path` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ga_views` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url_path` (`url_path`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3513 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

La misma fue llenada de forma masiva mediante una transacción que falló varias veces antes de funcionar.

Ahora yo tengo mis registros así:

```
id      url_path  ...
1       ... 
2       ...
3       ...
2682    ...
2683    ...
2684    ...
```

O sea, del `3` salta al `2682` y más adelante puede haber más saltos significativos, en caso de que la transacción haya fallado.

¿Cómo podría normalizar el valor de mi columna `id` ahora, antes de empezar a usar esa tabla en otras relaciones?

Quisiera tenerla así:

```
id      url_path  ...
1       ... 
2       ...
3       ...
4       ...
5       ...
6       ...
```

He probado con esto sin ningún éxito:

```
ALTER TABLE google_analytics AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

Comment: Actualmente tienes el id=1 asignado, para que tu código funcione debe hacerse con el siguiente no asignado: `ALTER TABLE google_analytics AUTO_INCREMENT = 4`

Comment: @WalterCordova gracias por tu comentario. Tampoco funciona así: `No errors. 0 rows affected` y los datos siguen como estaban antes.

Comment: lamentablemente el reordenar en mysql no existe, lo que muchos hacen es llevar los datos en una tabla temporal , eliminar la tabla base y luego hacer un select/insert de los datos deseado

Comment: Por lógica no debe de dejar por los id = 2682 .... y demás, ya que en algún momento  se perdería la integridad, no se si te convendría borrar esos id y reiniciar. Otra opción sería quitar el auto_increment y hacer una función que vaya a consultar el último id disponible e inserte ese}

Comment: Intente con `ALTER TABLE  google_analytics
  MODIFY  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=1;`

Comment: Tampoco @Jonathanch. Lo probé como dices, y también con `AUTO_INCREMENT=4` y nada.

Comment: lo único que le podría sugerir es que haga una consulta, cada vez que vaya a insertar un dato en la tabla, podría crearle un trigger a la tabla, y que ese trigger le ponga el último id consultado más 1.

Comment: Respecto a la integridad, si la tabla definió las conductas frente a UPDATE y DELETE durante su creación, en CASCADE, no debiera haber problemas si actualizan los id... o sí?

Comment: @quinqui la tabla no tiene ninguna norma establecida frente a `UPDATE` o `DELETE`. Por ahora no está relacionada con nadie en la BD, precisamente quiero normalizar esa diferencia (salto) de números antes de cualquier relación.

Comment: @JuanPinzón Postgres es un motor completamente distinto, el trabaja con Sequence Mysql con auto_increment aunque parezcan lo mismo son dos conceptos diferentes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si no tienes ninguna referencia a otra tabla, podrías usar el siguiente codigo

```
SET @count = 0;
UPDATE google_analytics SET google_analytics.id = @count:= @count + 1;
```

Y luego de esto para recuperar el auto_increment en el siguiente valor:

```
ALTER TABLE google_analytics  AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

En MYSQL reseteará el valor a MAX(id) + 1.

Comment: Gracias Juan, ha funcionado de maravilla. Muy importante el `ALTER TABLE` para resetear el AUTO_INCREMENT.

Comment: deben considerar que desde la version 8 de mysql phpmyadmin no actualiza los autoincrement...